# Calculate price using percentage from product field

Tags: drupal-commerce, discount, drupal-rules

I'm using drupal commerce module and drive with pricing rule problem. User and product have percentage fields, which are discount values separately. Final discount gathered from sum of this fields. How can I calculate line item price with discount fields?